# reprepro No section given for 'galera', skipping

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I'm trying to create a local repo using reprepro. Below are the steps and folder structure

I have created a directory my_repo

### Directory Structure

```
my_repo
--> conf
     --> distributions
     --> override
     --> override.precise.extra.main
     --> override.precise.main
     --> override.precise.main.debian-installer
```

### distributions

```
Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Codename: precise
Suite: stable
Version: 12.04
Architectures: amd64 i386
Components: main
DebOverride: override
UDebComponents: main
Description: GUI-Installer cd mirror
SignWith: yes
Pull: precise
```

Then I gave a below command to add the debian

### Cmd:

```
$> reprepro -V -b my_repo/ -C main includedeb precise galera_23.2.2_amd64.deb
```

Then it is failing to add the debian by giving the below are
No section give for 'galera', skipping.

Any pointers on this will be helpful

Comment: You can add a section either in the conf file or via '-S' command line switch. misc might be a good start there.

Comment: Thank you TeTeT i have added Priority and Section parameters in the override file which worked for me.